# how to add image to each category in wordpress?

Tags: image, wordpress, categories

i create the plugin to add image to each category,
i want to upload image at time of add category and also in edit category,
also in list of category i want to retrieve each category name with image

thanks in advance

have dream day

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-page-icons/

Maybe you can use that, or parts of it :)

Answer (score 6):

Use this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/categories-images/

it is so simple and so easy, you can find everything in documentation :)

Comment: how reliable this plugin is? I have my mobile apps synced to my website. Are you sure it would not break my website as well as apps